# Magento 2 Klarna checkout translate label

Tags: magento2, language, translate, klarna

How to translate "Signup to our newsletter" label to norwegian? Tried using Inline translation tool, but this line can't be translated using it. Also tried translating it in my i18n theme folder in nb_NO.csv like this:

```
"Signup to our newsletter","Registrer deg på vårt nyhetsbrev",module,Klarna_Core
"Signup to our newsletter","Registrer deg på vårt nyhetsbrev",module,Klarna_Kco_Core
"Signup to our newsletter","Registrer deg på vårt nyhetsbrev",module,Klarna_Kco
"Signup to our newsletter","Registrer deg på vårt nyhetsbrev"
```

None of them worked. Is there Norwegian language pack for Klarna checkout? Or what else I could try?

Comment: nb_NO.csv seems odd. shouldn't that be no_NO.csv?

Comment: We are using our own nb_NO.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to translate that label by extending /vendor/klarna/module-kco/etc/klarna.xml in my custom module and defining loading sequence.

Comment: Hi, Can you please elaborate what you did exactly as I also looking to translate "Signup to our newsletter" in checkout

Answer (score 0):

According to this language pack, you have to use `no_NO` as locale code instead of `nb_NO`

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-norwegian-language-pack.html

Comment: We are using our own nb_NO.csv.